# Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.'

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I have created console application in  Program.cs written below code

```
string fileToBackup = @"C:\Users\\Downloads\rootkey.csv"; // test file
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(fileToBackup));
            string myBucketName = "buckettest455"; //your s3 bucket name goes here
            string s3DirectoryName = "justdemodirectory";
            string s3FileName = @"rootkey.csv uploaded in 12-9-2014.zip";

            AmazonUploader myUploader = new AmazonUploader();
            myUploader.sendMyFileToS3(stream, myBucketName, s3DirectoryName, s3FileName);
```

in AmazonUploader.cs written below code

```
  public bool sendMyFileToS3(System.IO.Stream localFilePath, string bucketName, string subDirectoryInBucket, string fileNameInS3)
        {
            IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.APSouth1);
            TransferUtility utility = new TransferUtility(client);
            TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();

            if (subDirectoryInBucket == "" || subDirectoryInBucket == null)
            {
                request.BucketName = bucketName; //no subdirectory just bucket name  
            }
            else
            {   // subdirectory and bucket name  
                request.BucketName = bucketName + @"/" + subDirectoryInBucket;
            }
            request.Key = fileNameInS3; //file name up in S3  
            request.InputStream = localFilePath;
            utility.Upload(request); //commensing the transfer  

            return true; //indicate that the file was sent  
        }
```

and in App.config i have provided AWSAccessKey and AWSSecretKey

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="AWSProfileName" value="Ashok" />
    <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="" />
    <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="" />
    <!--AWSProfileName is used to reference an account that has been registered with the SDK.  
If using AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio then this value is the same value shown in the AWS Explorer.  
It is also possible to register an account using the <solution-dir>/packages/AWSSDK-X.X.X.X/tools/account-management.ps1 PowerShell script  
that is bundled with the nuget package under the tools folder.  
  
        <add key="AWSProfileName" value="" />  
-->
  </appSettings>
```

Now whenever i am trying and run application getting below exception

Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.' in line

```
utility.Upload(request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to create AWS credentials for your env
There are 2 ways:

1. Create it manually
2. Instal aws sdk and use command line
   Here is manual
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/creds-file.html